# Форматирование кода (лишние переносы строк)

Tags: html, phpstorm, sublime-text, форматирование

После выгрузки проекта с хостинга заметил, что некоторые файлы имеют такое форматирование (повторяющаяся пустая строка).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как привести код к нормальному виду (использую Sublime Text 3 PHP-Storm).
И как не допустить подобного в будущем?

Comment: *как не допустить подобного в будущем?* - на сколько я знаю это так хостинг балуется, уже и не помню зачем.

Comment: Для форматирования в PHPStrom выделяете код  и  нажмите Ctrl +Alt +L
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformatting-source-code.html

Comment: Онлайн реформатор кода Html https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему такое происходит - не очень понятно, возможно, это проблемы хостинга.
Чтобы исправить форматирование, попробуйте следующее:

- В **File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other**, установите **Keep blank lines** в `0`.
- После этого отформатируйте файл (**Code | Reformat Code**, `Ctrl+Alt+L`)